# get a string without ""

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to automate the setup-process in PyCaret Library.
The goal is to create a list of "experiments" and the script should iretate over the list of elements.

In the setup could be following preprocessing steps chosen:
feature_selection = True,
remove_outliers = True, etc.

All such pre-processing steps i would like to store in a list and then run a loop in order to find the best setting (best performance) for the model.

For example:

```
a = "feature_selection = True"
b = "remove_outliers = True"
```

etc..

But when i call the variable "a" in the setup i get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-0d8c8dcb30cf>", line 7
    a
    ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

because the variable "a" does not the job well.

```
reg = setup(data = df, silent = True, test_data = dff, target = 'Thickness',
            verbose = False,
            numeric_features = ['Airbubbles','PreHeat','PlugTemp','AirPres','VacPress','MoldTemp'],
            a
           )
```

If i call the variable "a" the following is being shown:
'feature_selection = True'

Thefore i need to store strings for the list in some other way, in order to be displayed as: feature_selection = True (without '') AND accepted by the setup from PyCaret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a string like this:

```
>>> a = "feature_selection = True"
>>> a
"feature_selection = True"
```

In order to pass that as a keyword argument (kwarg) to a function (e.g., `my_func(feature_selection=True)`), you need to convert it to a dict:

```
>>> import re
>>> d = dict([re.split('\s*=\s*', a)])
{'feature_selection': 'True'}
```

You might want to convert the keys to actual literal values, e.g. `'True'` (string) -> `True` (boolean):

```
import ast

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)
```

Then, you can pass it to a function like this:

```
my_func(**d)
```

e.g.

```
reg = setup(data = df, silent = True, test_data = dff, target = 'Thickness',
            verbose = False,
            numeric_features = ['Airbubbles','PreHeat','PlugTemp','AirPres','VacPress','MoldTemp'],
            **d,
           )
```